# Does this area simply connected?[complex- line integral]

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

This is a clear theorem in complex analysis.

For simply connected area $D (\subset \mathbb{C})$
$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red] {f \in H(D)  \Rightarrow \exists F s.t. F'(z) = f(z)}$$

(Here $H(D)$ means a set of the analytic functions on $D$)

---

Then Let me consider the $f(z) = z^{1\over2}$ for $D = \{z \vert -{3\pi\over2} \leq arg(z) \lt {\pi\over 2} \}$

(Here the $D$ means  $\mathbb{C}$ without branch cut. )

Say curve the  $\gamma = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \vert \Vert z\Vert =1 \}$

I knew the $\int_\gamma f dz \neq 0$. by defintion of the line-integral that $\int_\gamma f(t) \bullet z'(t) dt $

Then Is the Area $D$ not simply connected?(In my thought Supposing the D is simply connected, the $F(z)$ would be exists. Hence, the value of the line integer should be $0$. But the result is not. ) Is my thought and result right? I'm so curious.

Also If my thought incorrect please let me know why it is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: The definition of $D$ does not make sense.

Comment: What does $z \leq \pi /2$ mean?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy :  Err.. I found typo. Sorry. :(

Comment: Dear Mr.@KaviRamaMurthy : I edited. Thanks for what I've missed.

Comment: How is your $D$ not all of $\Bbb C$ (or at least $\Bbb C^\times$)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : Does your $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ mean $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$? $

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I'm not sure if this is done, but one might consider that as $\mathbb C^\times$ employed with the topology of $\mathbb R^+\times [-\frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ transported to $\mathbb C^\times$ through the polar map. Functions that in the ordinary topology are discontinuous only on the branch cut are continuous under this topology.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang: Essentially, yes, it is $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$. More generally, the superscript times symbol denotes the set of invertible elements; since in $\mathbb C$ (and in fields in general) all non-zero elements are invertible, in this case it amounts to just removing the zero.

Comment: Dear @celtschk, Then we can the considering $D$  is a $C-\{0\}$ for the branch point $0$.  Hence $D$ is not simply connected right?

Comment: If interpreted as subset of $\mathbb C$ under the subset topology, your $D$ is indeed not simply connected. A simple way to fix that is to replace the left $\le$ sign by a $<$ sign, at the cost of not covering all of $\mathbb C^\times$. An alternative is to do the cut also in the topology, which essentially is what I suggested in my reply to Hagen von Eitzen's comment. In that “cut topology”, with your choice of cut to the right of the imaginary axis, the set $\{z\in\mathbb C \vert \operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$ is disconnected because it is cut into two parts by the branch cut.

Comment: Note however that this“cut topology” is my own idea, which I've not thought through; as I wrote in the answer to HvE, I don't know if this is actually done. So there might be some pitfalls in it that I don't see. The "remove the complete cut line" method is guaranteed safe.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ be a region where an analytic function $f(x)=z^{\frac12}$ can be defined (i.e., analytic $f\colon D\to \Bbb C$ with $f(z)^2=z$ for al $z\in D$). By differentiating $f(z)^2=z$, we find $2f(z)f'(z)=1$. Hence $f(z)\ne 0$ in $D$. We conclude that $0\notin D$. Recall that $D$ is simply connected iff both $D$ and $(\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\})\setminus D$ are connected. As $0\notin D$ and $\infty\notin D$, there cannot exist any curve (such as the unit circle) in a simply-connected $D$ that separates $0$ from $\infty$

Comment: I'm not sure your answer exactly I understood. Your answer means There aren't any curve separate the $0$ form $\infty$(I.e. connected spaces), Hence it is simply connected. Is it right?